# JWT 'RS256' Algorithm issue

Tags: ios, swift, jwt

I used this library for generating JWT token here is my code :

```
func generateJWT() -> String{
    let claim = JWTClaimsSet()
    claim.issuer = "xxxxxx"
    claim.audience = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    claim.issuedAt = NSDate()
    claim.expirationDate = NSDate()

    let header = ["alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"]
    let algorithm = JWTAlgorithmFactory.algorithmByName("RS256")

    let encodeBuilder = JWT.encodeClaimsSet(claim)
    let jwt = encodeBuilder.secret("secret").algorithm(algorithm).headers(header).encode

    return jwt
}
```

But i'm getting this error :

```
2016-03-30 16:51:23.274 JWTObjc[3217:74974] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
```

I did anything wrong ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Which line exactly? There is a `nil` value somewhere.

Comment: In this line : let jwt = encodeBuilder.secret("secret").algorithm(algorithm).headers(header).encode

Comment: HS256 working fine but RS256 i got the error above

Comment: `algorithm` is `nil`?

Comment: No it's not nil i displayed alogorithm object i got : <JWTAlgorithmRS256: 0x7879d260>

Comment: In `encodeHelper()` of JWT.m, `signedOutput` is nil at the end. Are you missing a setting in case of RS256?

Comment: i just imported "JWT.h" & "JWTAlgorithmFactory.h" into my Bridging-Header, did i miss something ?

Comment: RSA algorithms require a private key to sign, not a shared secret.  I'm not sure what the APIs require in this case, but it's almost certainly not an NSString secret.  It might be an NSData, which could represent the private key, and you might also require a passphrase if the data is in PKCS12 format (which is the most likely requirement).  I suppose it could expect base64URL encoded data as the "secret".

Comment: it's possible to show me how i can do it with code ? in github link they are saying "Additional algorithms can be added by implementing the JWTAlgorithm protocol."

Comment: I want to achieve this tutorial : [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)

Comment: I think I found the project -- I think you want to use .secretData(p12FileData).privateKeyCertificatePassphrase("password") instead of .secret("secret").

Comment: Can you share with me how exactly you solved this issue..???

Comment: I am using the same code but 'Optional((Function))' instead the token. @yourself .Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMAC signature signing/verification involves a shared secret known by both sides, thus the use of the .secret("secret") method there.

RSA is a public/private key system, where the signer has the private key, and the verifier has only the public key.  So, to create the signed JWT, you need the private key instead.  These are most often used in PKCS12 format, protected by a passphrase.  It looks like that is how the JWTAlgorithmRS256 class is expecting it, so the API there looks more like `.secretData(p12FileData).privateKeyCertificatePassphrase("password")` instead of `.secret("secret")`.

For verification, you probably want `.secretData(certFileData)` (the cert would contain the public key).

Answer (score 0):

i use PKCS1 with RS256

```
 func encryptPayload(payload:[AnyHashable:Any])->String?
{
    var resultStr: String?

    var publicKeyCrypto: JWTCryptoKeyProtocol? = nil
    do {
        publicKeyCrypto = try JWTCryptoKeyPublic(pemEncoded: AppConstant.Scurity.publicKey, parameters: nil)
    }
    catch {
        NSLog("error: \(error)")
    }

    guard let theCrypto = publicKeyCrypto else {
        return nil
    }

    do {

        let privateKeyCrypto = try JWTCryptoKeyPrivate(pemEncoded: AppConstant.Scurity.privateKey, parameters: nil)

        guard let holder = JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder().signKey(privateKeyCrypto)?.secretData(AppConstant.Scurity.privateKey.data(using: .utf8))?.algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameRS256) else {return nil}

        let headers : [AnyHashable:Any] = ["alg": "RS256","typ": "JWT"]

        guard let encoding = JWTEncodingBuilder.encodePayload(payload).headers(headers)?.addHolder(holder) else {return nil}

        let result = encoding.result

        print(result?.successResult?.encoded ?? "Encoding failed")
        print(result?.errorResult?.error ?? "No encoding error")

        let verifyDataHolder = JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder().signKey(theCrypto)?.secretData(AppConstant.Scurity.publicKey.data(using: .utf8)!)?.algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameRS256)

        let verifyResult = JWTDecodingBuilder.decodeMessage(result?.successResult?.encoded).addHolder(verifyDataHolder)?.result

        if verifyResult?.successResult != nil, let result = verifyResult?.successResult.encoded {
            print("Verification successful, result: \(result)")
        } else {
            print("Verification error: \(verifyResult!.errorResult.error)")
        }
        resultStr = result?.successResult.encoded
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return resultStr
}
```